# Does anyone know how to get Call of Duty multiplayer working on Ubuntu?

Tags: games

I've tried Lutris and WINE but I still can't get the game to work. My plan is to get away from Windows and be fully on Linux when is comes to gaming.

How can I get it working on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Lutris? You can install it here https://lutris.net/downloads and then find your game inside it and install it, it will add WineHQ/proton configuration, that can make it work under Linux.